# Eclipse, Java, import suddenly stopped being recognize

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have a java project with several packages.

```
com.xxx.simulator
        ThreadManager.java
        Simulator.java
com.example
        Config.java
```

`Simulator` and `Config` both import `ThreadManager`. I did not have any problem until now. I opened Eclipse and had this errors showing:

> The import com.xxx.simulator.ThreadManager cannot be resolved

and

> ThreadManager cannot be resolved

---

This is ThreadManager:

```
package com.xxx.simulator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ThreadManager implements ThreadFactory { }
```

This is Config

```
    package com.example;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.xxx.simulator.Simulator;
    import com.xxx.simulator.ThreadManager;    <----- The import cannot be resolved
    import com.xxx.simulator.config.Configuration;

    @Path("config")
    public class Config {
    // some stuff
    ThreadManager.getInstance().getAllThreadStatus();   <----- ThreadManager cannot be resolved (on ThreadManager only)
 }
```

To fix `ThreadManager cannot be resolved`, I am proposed to import `ThreadManager` from `com.xxx.simulator`. But it already is imported with the `Import cannot be resolved` error.

How can I solve this ? Any solution proposed by Eclipse is not working.

Edit: The problem is for Config.java AND Simulator.java.

Edit 2: ThreadManager is the only class causing this problem from com.xxx.simulator.

Comment: Worth rechecking if there is any typo in package name or import in your code (Though I am sure you would have checked, worth checking once more :) )

Comment: @Smile I checked. No error. Strange thing is that ThreadManager is the only class causing this problem. other classes from com.xxx.simulator are OK when imported.

Comment: Try a clean build of the project in eclipse. If it is a maven project, then try running mvn eclipse:eclipse through command line.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo That solved the issue. Could you explain why it had to be done ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Sometimes eclipse lands in a state where it is no longer able to identify / find the generated class files / jars. So, we usually do a clean build or mvn eclipse:eclipse to get all the dependencies (classes/jars) correctly set up.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo Ok, thanks. If you can add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a clean build of the project in eclipse. If it is a maven project, then try running mvn eclipse:eclipse through command line.

**Reasoning:**
Sometimes eclipse lands in a state where it is no longer able to identify / find the generated class files / jars. So, we usually do a clean build or mvn eclipse:eclipse to get all the dependencies (classes/jars) correctly set up. This is essentially rebuilding the project so that all relationships, dependencies, metadata is correctly set up to recognize the dependencies successfully.